# How to find text with single quotes without using Like in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a column (named MyColumn) which elements like '1', '2', '3' and etc.
I d like to get everything from MyTable where Mycolumn is equal to '1'
I tried this query

```
select * from MyTable where MyColumn='1'   --- i've get 0 rows
```

Also i tried

```
select * from MyTable where MyColumn='\'1\'';
```

how can i find text elements which are also in single quotes?

Comment: Can you include a sample of actual data that you'd expect to find?  Are there trailing spaces, or other characters?  You can strip out unwanted characters with the REPLACE function, as in replace(MyColumn, '[','')

Comment: what is the type of myColumn ?

Comment: Which programming language are you using? All of them support quoting of values, in one way or another. Please use this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes (not "brackets") are escaped by doubling them in SQL:

```
select * 
from MyTable 
where MyColumn='''1''';
```

This is also well documented in the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what you usually do ([doubling apostrophes / single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33549239/521799)) in such a situation, I'd like to point out the fact that in PostgreSQL, you can use "dollar escaping" in case you have longer strings that potentially contain lots of "special characters". Your statement would then be:

```
select * from MyTable where MyColumn = $$'1'$$;
```

Or, if you risk having double-dollars in your string:

```
select * from MyTable where MyColumn = $THISWILLNEVERAPPEAR$'1'$THISWILLNEVERAPPEAR$;
```

See also:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING